# mySql INNER JOIN, MAX & DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I'm looking to return one row for each user of type "student" displaying their "name" and their latest "score" (in reverse chronological order).

I have two tables users & services

users Table

```
id  name    type
---|-------|-----
1  | Bob   | student 
2  | Dave  | student
3  | Larry | student
4  | Kevin | master
```

services table

```
id   score   userId  date
---|--------|-------|------------
1  | 14     | 1     | 2014-09-04
2  | 99     | 3     | 2014-09-03
3  | 53     | 2     | 2014-09-07
4  | 21     | 1     | 2014-09-08
5  | 79     | 2     | 2014-09-08
6  | 43     | 3     | 2014-09-10
7  | 72     | 3     | 2014-09-10
8  | 66     | 2     | 2014-09-01
9  | 43     | 3     | 2014-08-22
10 | 26     | 1     | 2014-08-22
```

Desired Result

```
id   scores   name   date
---|--------|-------|------------
3  | 43     | Larry | 2014-09-10
1  | 21     | Bob   | 2014-09-08
2  | 79     | Dave  | 2014-09-08
```

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, services.date, services.score
FROM users 
JOIN services ON users.id = services.userId
WHERE users.type='student'
ORDER BY services.date DESC
```

But this always returns the last date in the table for each user.

So i decided to try and tackle it from the other end like this:

```
SELECT servicesTemp.date, servicesTemp.score
FROM services servicesTemp
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT userId, MAX(date) AS MaxExpDate
    FROM services
    GROUP BY clientId) servicesTempGrp 
ON servicesTemp.userId = servicesTempGrp.userId 
AND servicesTemp.MaxDate = servicesTempGrp.MaxDate
```

But realised that i would end up with duplicates if the dates were ever the same and i can only return one row per user (and double grouping didn't work).

I think i'm now over complicating this, so a life line would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you choose between 43 and 72 as the score for Larry?

Comment: in this case it doesn't really matter, as long as only one is returned.

Comment: @TraceyTurn : Yes it does....because your `date` and `score`s are not in sync...do you ant just *any* `score` to be returned?

Comment: yes any score as long as it's one from the most recent date for that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, services.date, services.score
FROM users 
JOIN services ON users.id = services.userId
WHERE users.type='client'
AND services.date = (SELECT MAX(date) from services where userID = users.id)
ORDER BY services.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can guarantee one row by using the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, max(s.date) as date,
       substring_index(group_concat(s.score order by date desc), ',', 1) as score
FROM users u JOIN
     services s
     ON u.id = s.userId
WHERE u.type = 'client'
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY s.date DESC;
```

Without using `group by`, another option for getting only one row per user is to use variables.  Or, if you know the ids are being assigned sequentially, use the `id` instead of `date`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, s.date, s.score
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     services s
     on u.userId = s.userId INNER JOIN
     (SELECT userId, MAX(id) AS MaxId
      FROM services
      GROUP BY userId
     ) smax
     ON s.userId = smax.userId and s.Id = smax.MaxId
WHERE u.type = 'client';
```